# RewritePath in asp.net mvc 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this in a legacy asp.net mvc app:

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(url, false)
```

as part of the authorization process. It does not seem to work. Could this be a config issue or could the routing process swallow this? Any pointers would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the execution reaches that line of code?

Comment: Could this be that this only works for cookieless sessions?